# indicating that the package has already been uploaded

Tags: ios

Using the iOS launch tool appuploader to submit the app upload steps, the prompt "Upload failed, you have already uploaded this package" appears. Multiple methods have been tried but the problem cannot be resolved. We hope to seek help[image]